# Can't login after purging

Tags: gnome, package-management

I was trying to remove libssl in order reinstall an older version, so I typed a command to purge it and by accident I actually purged A LOT of more things, like apps and important OS packages.

Long story short, I rebooted the machine and now I cant pass the login screen (after typing password, it just comes back to login menu again).

I managed to save the terminal list of purges and this is it:

> compizconfig-settings-manager crda dh-python dnsutils fabric
>   flashplugin-installer foomatic-db-compressed-ppds galera-3 gconf2 gdb
>   gdebi gdebi-core gedit gimp gimp-help-en gimp-help-pt gir1.2-ibus-1.0
>   git-cola gksu gnome-control-center gnome-gmail gnome-menus gnome-orca
>   gnome-terminal grub-customizer gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gvfs-backends
>   gyp hollywood hplip hplip-data ibus ibus-table icoutils
>   indicator-bluetooth indicator-kdeconnect indicator-sound-switcher
>   indicator-stickynotes kdeconnect kio-extras language-selector-common
>   language-selector-gnome libapache2-mod-php7.0 libaprutil1
>   libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libbind9-140 libbonoboui2-0
>   libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libcurl3
>   libdns162 libemail-valid-perl libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1
>   libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1
>   libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1
>   libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-utils1.1 libgksu2-0
>   libgnome-2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnome2-perl
>   libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common
>   libgnomevfs2-extra libhpmud0 libio-socket-ssl-perl libisccfg140 lib
>   lwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libnet-dbus-perl
>   libnet-dropbox-api-perl libnet-oauth-perl firefox  gnome-tweak-tool
>   google-chrome-stable libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18

I tried ctrl+shift+f1 to access terminal and reinstall all this, but I seems I don-t have wlan0 and eth0 anymore

Comment: The ends of `/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` should have a more confident list of removals.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have? If you have systemd (Ubuntu 15.04 or later), you won't have `wlan0` or `eth0`, you'll have some longer thing. Try `ifconfig` to see if anything other than `lo` comes up.